# How to check in NAnt script whether property is set or not?

Tags: xml, release, nant, nantcontrib

Hi I am create a release script using NAnt. How can I check a variable value is getting or not.

Now I call my script like this

```
    nant -buildfile:CreateNew.build -D:name="Test.V.1.0" -D:bIDs="2" -D:uIDs="'3'"
```

Some times I will not pass uIDs.

So I need to check in my nant script whether the uIDs is getting or not. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a [`property::exists`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/property.exists%28System.String%29.html) function that you should use:

```
<if test="${property::exists('uIDs')}">
  <echo message="uIDs is set" />
</if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most (or even all?) NAnt tasks have if/unless attributes. You can use property::exists() function in conjunction with those attributes to condition your build script.